# Contorno dos bairros utilizando a API do Google Maps

Tags: javascript, jquery, google-maps

Ola! Estou criando um mapa para visualização de um município com todos os bairros. Utilizando do kmz disponibilizado pelo IBGE eu consegui contornar o município que eu quero, porém não achei nenhum kmz para os bairros. Notei que pesquisando um bairro no próprio Google maps ele retorna o mesmo contornado, é possível fazer isso utilizando a API do Maps com Javascript ?

Abaixo tem um exemplo de uma pesquisa no Google Maps do Brás em São Paulo:

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Comment: A sua pergunta é um pouco ampla, deveria ser restrita a um ponto específico onde está encontrando dificuldades e incluir a parte do código referente ao mesmo.

Comment: Aparentemente isso não é possível através da API do Google Maps.